# is the following a decreasing function?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I am stuck on figuring out why the following function is a decreasing function when I read a paper. The function is following 
$$f(x)=-\frac{1}{x}\log[{pe^{-ax}+(1-p)e^{-bx}}]$$ 
where $a$ and $b$ are two arbitrary non-zero constants (can be negative or positive), but $a$ is not equal to $b$ and $p \in(0,1)$. 
I am stuck on figuring out why $f(x)$ is globally decreasing in $x \in R$ for any choice of $a, b$.

I find the first derivative as follows, for any  $a, b$.
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}\log[{pe^{-ax}+(1-p)e^{-bx}}]+\frac{1}{x}\frac{ape^{-ax}+b(1-p)e^{-bx}}{{pe^{-ax}+(1-p)e^{-bx}}}$$ 
But then I get stuck, how to show it's negative for all $x \in R$? I use mathematica to  plot this function, and it is indeed decreasing in $x$, but I can't proceed further on how to show this analytically

Any hint or help is extremely appreciated!

Edited: To make thing more interesting..in fact I am considering the case $a$ is not equal to $b$ and $p$ is interior in (0,1)..

Comment: This is false when $a=b$ -- the function is constant then.

Comment: @IgorRivin Thank you for pointing out, but I think I am considering the case $a$ is not equal to $b$

Comment: $qe^{-ax} + re^{-bx}$ is decreasing. What about $(qe^{-ax} + re^{-bx})^{1/x}$ Can you show it is increasing?  Then so is log $(qe^{-ax} + re^{-bx})^{1/x}$ and its negative will be decreasing.

Comment: @BettyMock Thanks for the help, from your advise, I find that to show $(qe^{-ax}+re^{-bx})^{\frac{1}{x}}$ is increasing, the first derivative tells me it's enough to show $\log(qe^{-ax}+re^{-bx})$ is negative, but don't know how to deal with this

Comment: @BettyMock One can't say $pe^{-ax}+(1-p)e^{-bx}$ is decreasing without some assumption such as $a,b>0$ which OP doesn't assume, and also doesn't seem to be required for $f(x)$ to wind up decreasing.

Comment: @coffeemath quite so, I was thinking of them as positive

Comment: @papayoan  did you do the first derivative of $(qe^{-ax} +re^{-bx})^{1/x}$ right?  I don't see how a log would get into it.  Also, notice the comment from coffeemath, where he correctly points out I was assuming a and b positive.  No harm in doing a special case first, but then the problem has to be completed.

Comment: The first derivative of $f(x)^{g(x)}$ certainly involves a log. To apply derivative laws, one first converts to $e^{g(x)\ln f(x)}.$

Answer (score 4):

$f(x)=-\frac{1}{x}\log({pe^{-ax}+(1-p)e^{-bx}})=\log[({pe^{-ax}+(1-p)e^{-bx}})^{-\frac{1}{x}}]$

observe that f(x) is increasing (resp decreasing) iff $g(x)=({pe^{-ax}+(1-p)e^{-bx}})^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ is increasing ( resp decreasing).

claim: if $a>b$ f is  globally decreasing:
proof:

let: $h(x)=\frac{1}{x}log(\frac{1}{(p+(1-p)e^{(a-b)x})})$ 
$h(x)$ is a globally decreasing function regardless of the values of a,b and p and i wil explain why at the end of this proof. let's assume this fact for now and later on we will see the justification.
now let $x<y$ then: $h(y)<h(x)$

then $\frac{1}{y}\log(\frac{1}{(p+(1-p)e^{(a-b)y})})<\frac{1}{x}log(\frac{1}{(p+(1-p)e^{(a-b)x})})$
thus:

$\log(\frac{1}{(p+(1-p)e^{(a-b)y})})^{\frac{1}{y}}<\log(\frac{1}{(p+(1-p)e^{(a-b)x})})^{\frac{1}{x}}$
hence

$(p+(1-p)e^{(a-b)y})^{\frac{-1}{y}}<(p+(1-p)e^{(a-b)x})^{\frac{-1}{x}}$ now multiply both sides by $e^{a}$ and end up with :

$(e^{-ay}(p+(1-p)e^{(a-b)y}))^{\frac{-1}{y}}<(e^{-ax}(p+(1-p)e^{(a-b)x}))^{\frac{-1}{x}}$

that is

$({pe^{-ay}+(1-p)e^{-by}})^{-\frac{1}{y}}<({pe^{-ax}+(1-p)e^{-bx}})^{-\frac{1}{x}}$

which implies that g(x) is decreasing and consequently f(x) is decreasing.

to show that h(x) is globally decreasing:

let $Z(x)=p+(1-p)e^{(a-b)x}$ then $ h(x)=-\frac{1}{x}log(Z(x))$

$h^{'}(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}(log(Z(x)-x\frac{Z^{'}(x)}{Z(x)})$ then the sign of $h^{'}$ is the same as the sign of $L(x)=log(Z(x)-x\frac{Z^{'}(x)}{Z(x)}$ from here it is easy to show that L(x) (by studying its derivative) is increasing when x<0 and decreasing when x>0 where L(x) is taking a finite limit at x=0 ( which i believe is zero )therefore L(x) is always below (or equal to zero) and the same follows for $h^{'}$ which implies finally that h is decreasing.

Now for the case b>a we will consider another function:$\frac{1}{x}log(\frac{1}{(pe^{(b-a)x}+(1-p)})$ which is just the same as h(x), use the same technique used above and prove that f is decreasing.

Comment: When $a=2,b=1,p=0.4$ look at the graph of $f(x)$ via any graphing device. It is decreasing for all reals, and here $a>b$ [so this goes against your claim it should increase when $x<0$

Comment: thanks a lot coffemath for pointing that out . i will provide the proof later on today. when $x<0$ the inequality changes twice.

Comment: @toufic_kh.17  Of course there is also the third case where $x<0<y$, though it might be trivial. Interesting how many gyrations are needed to get the inequality to work out, and I for one hope to see the other cases done so this inequality can finally be shown to hold for any $p,a,b$. And +1...

Comment: In the step between the line starting "and" and the line starting "then": In one line you have something of the form $\log A<\log B$ and you can show that both of these logs are negative numbers. Then to get the next line you proceed to multiply the first by $1/y$ and the second by $1/x$, and presumably use that $1/y<1/x$ [true here]. But this is not (without further information) a valid inequality step. That is, from $u<v<0$ and $0<a<b$ it does not necessarily follow that $au<bv$, as one can see by cooking up examples. Something more specific is needed about how the terms interact.

Comment: @coffeemath thanks a lot for  the excellent observations . i hope you approve the approach i used to avoid the issue.

Comment: i think the same approach i used to prove that h(x) is globally decreasing could have been used for f(x) ( not sure though i haven't tried yet).

Answer (score 4):

This answer is added to the others mainly because its methods are different, and (at least to me) make the argument less involved. Working with the derivative of the original function is difficult because of the presence of a log term added to a rational term.  I hope that someone finds this approach interesting, if only as a variant one.
First note that, since we wish to show the inequality of the OP holds for all real $a \neq b$, we'll use $a,b$ rather than the $-a,-b$ in front of the $x$ in the two exponentials. We will also drop the initial minus sign in front of the whole function, and then the OP function is decreasing iff our altered function is increasing. These adjustments just make the algebra go smoother and don't affect the argument.
Let $f(x)$ be denoted referring to its parameters as 
$$f(p,a,b,x)=\frac{1}{x} \log(p e^{ax}+(1-p)e^{bx}).$$ 
Note that then $f(p,a,b,x)=f(1-p,b,a,x).$ Thus we may assume that $a>b$ since if this is not so we may replace $p$ by $1-p$ and interchange the letters $a,b.$  Let $k=a-b>0.$ Then $a=b+k$ and using $e^{ax}=e^{bx}e^{kx}$ we arrive at a form similar to that used in other posts:
$$f(x)=b+ \frac{1}{x} \log(pe^{kx}+1-p).$$
Now let $t=kx$ and note that since $k>0$ we have $t$ increases with $x$, and then from the above, after dropping the initial added constant $b$ and rewriting the initial fraction as $k\cdot \frac{1}{kx},$ and  also dropping the initial positive factor $k$, we see that $f(x)$ will be  increasing iff $g(t)$ is increasing, where
$$g(t)=\frac{1}{t} \log(p e^t +1-p).$$
[Note that in the parameter notation this is $f(p,1,0,t)$, so that so far we've just reduced the problem to a particular case.]

Note that as it stands $g(0)$ is not defined; however L'Hopital shows the limit as $t \to 0$ of $g(t)$ is the parameter $p$. And note also for later that $g$ is analytic on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \} .$

Now $g(t)$ has the properties that $0 < g(t) < 1$ and that $g(t) \to 0$ as $t \to -\infty$ and $g(t) \to 1$ as $t \to \infty.$ These properties are simple to show, and I'll add details if anyone asks. In particular the range of $g$ is the open interval $(0,1).$

MAIN CLAIM: $g'(t) \ge 0$ for all $t.$

Otherwise choose a fixed $t_1$ at which $g'(t_1)<0.$ Then one can choose points $a,b$ near $t_1$ for which $a<t_1<b$ and also $f(a)>f(t_1)>f(b).$ Now since $g$ is continuous on $(-\infty,a]$ and goes to $0$ at $-\infty$, there is by the intermediate value theorem some point $t_0<a$ for which $g(t_0)=g(t_1).$ Similarly, since $g$ goes to $1$ at $+\infty$  there is some point $t_2>b$ for which $g(t_2)=g(t_1).$ So from the assumption that $g'(t_1)<0$, we have produced three points $t_0<t_1<t_2$ at each of which $g$ has the same value, say $a$, i.e.
$$g(t_0)=g(t_1)=g(t_2)=a.$$
Now assuming $t\neq 0$ we may take the equation $g(t)=a,$ multiply through by $t$ and expontiate, and obtain the equivalent equation $w(t)=0$ where
$$w(t)=pe^t+1-p-e^{at}.$$
Note that if $t=0$ then $w(0)=0$ holds no matter what the values of $p,a$ are. From the above, viewing $a$ as the constant common value of the $g(t_j),$  we see that $w(t)=a$ has the three distinct solutions $t_0<t_1<t_2$. So by Rolle's theorem there are two distinct values $t_a,t_b$, one in each open interval $(t_0,t_1)$ and $(t_1,t_2)$, where $w'(t_a)=w'(t_b)=0.$ But calculating $w'$ gives 
$$w'(t)=pe^t-ae^{at}$$
so that $w'(t)=0$ implies $pe^t=ae^{at}$, then $e^{t-at}=a/p$, so that $e^{(1-a)t}=a/p$ which has only one solution, since the constant $1-a$ is not zero (recall $0<a<1$). Thus $w'(t)=0$ does not have two distinct solutions, contradicting the two solutions guaranteed above using Rolle's theorem. This completes our argument for the main claim.

Now that we know $f'(t)\ge 0$ it only remains to show that in fact $f$ is strictly increasing. But this follows from $f' \ge 0$ by the fact that $f$ is analytic except at $0$, because an analytic nonconstant function cannot be zero at every point in an open interval.

Comment: Your initial simplification of the problem reduced a whole lot of computational effort. And in the later part you have done a further simplification by getting rid of log function itself. This makes the analysis of zeroes of $w(t) = c$ reasonably easy. +1 for a very simple (although non-obvious) solution.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh -- Yes I thought that, though involved to set it up, the final few steps did not need any complicated derivatives. (Also it was $w(t)=a$ in the notation, I had $c$ in there at one place but it was a typo, now fixed.)

Answer (score 2):

Let $b=a+\epsilon$ 
With a little bit of algebra:
$$f(x)=-\frac{1}{x} \log[pe^{-ax}+(1-p)e^{-(a+\epsilon)x}]$$

$$=-\frac{1}{x} \log[e^{-ax}(p+(1-p)e^{-\epsilon x})]$$ 
$$=-\frac{1}{x} \log[e^{-ax}\exp[\ln[(p+(1-p)e^{-\epsilon x})]]]$$
$$=-\frac{1}{x} \{\log[e^{-ax}]+\log[\exp[\log[(p+(1-p)e^{-\epsilon x})]]]\}$$
$$=a-x^{-1}\log[p+(1-p)e^{-\epsilon x}]$$

$$f'(x) = \frac{[(\epsilon(p-1)x+[p(-e^{\epsilon x}+p-1]\log(p-(p-1)e^{-\epsilon x}))]}{x^2[p(e^{\epsilon x})-1]+1}$$
After some careful calculations.

Then choose $\epsilon=-1$ and $p=0.0001\neq 0$ and evaluate at $x=1$, you will find evaluate $f'(x=1;\epsilon=-1,p=0.0001) = 0.718228>0$ this of course shows that the function is not strictly decreasing because the derivative is positive at this point.  There are other points you may evaluate yourself if you want.

Comment: @Squrtle Thanks for the reply but I am confused with third line, should that be $$-\frac{1}{x}\log[e^{-ax}(p+(1-p)e^{-\epsilon x})]=a-\frac{1}{x}\log(p+(1-p)e^{-\epsilon x})$$

Comment: Typo!Thanks for spotting it.... I left out the - sign

Comment: Sorry for all the edits.....  I am final on it now!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and effort, really appreciate it, but still, I am not clear if the third line is should be like the way it is in my first comment...also I am interested in the cases, in fact, $p$ cannot be equal to either 0 or 1...

Comment: I may have been confusing because I forgot a ) just before my ] in the 2nd line.  In any case, it is corrected now, and the Log and Exp cancel and the -ax is pulled out the rest of the terms in [...] stay.  As far as choices for $p$ I think this is a great exercise for you.

Comment: Btw, if you appreciate teh help and effort.... really appreciate it.  Upvote and select as top answer, I'd be glad to provide more if you want.

Comment: thanks but still obviously $\log(ab)$ is not equal to $(\log(a))b$, so the third line still missing log in front of $(p+(1-p)e^{-\epsilon x})$

Comment: WOW!  Thanks.... I am a bit tired.

Comment: Squirtle [re. papayoan's first comment above] Not only is the sign wrong, but the factor $1/x$ has been dropped from in front of the log part. It cannot be dropped, and that makes the derivative calculation not so simple as you arrive at.

Comment: Yup... right again.

Comment: @coffeemath thank you for your comment.  It helped me spot my mistake (which was similar but not nearly as bad as my first one).  None the less, I'm certain at this point that the OP is convinced the function is not strictly decreasing.

Comment: @Squirtle I would appreciate a specific example of values for $p,a,b$ for which the OP's function $f(x)$ is not strictly decreasing. Because I've tried a lot of them, some with $a,b$ the same sign, others with them of opposite sign, and in every case I tried I got a strictly decreasing $f(x)$ on graphing it.

Comment: Your formula for $f'(x)$ is not right. Done on maple, the derivative when $p=.0001,\epsilon=-1,x=1$ is $(-2.64237...)\cdot 10^{-5}.$

Comment: I disagree.... I used wolfram alpha.  You are welcome to correct it if you want.

Comment: @Squirtle In my previous comment I may have used the wrong parameters. I'd appreciate it if you could reply in a comment how to get the values of $a,b$ in the original function which, using the value $p=0.0001$ at the end of your answer, wind up giving a positive derivative at $x=1$. Maybe $a$ doesn't matter since it "drops out" on rephrasing in terms of your $\epsilon$, nevertheless I got confused in the translation and would appreciate specific $a,b,p$ for your example. Thanks...